# C++ function that returns 0,1 or -1

Tags: c++, function, return

Im new to programming and Im having trouble in writing a function in c++ that takes an integer "n" as a parameter and reads "n" integers from the keyboard,
Returning one of the following values:

- 0 , if all integers are even number;
- 1 , if all integers are uneven numbers;
- -1 , if among all integers there are even and uneven numbers;

How can I do this without using an array for the "n" value?

Comment: Do you already know how you will name the function?:)

Comment: How would you do it with an array?

Comment: What should happen for `n = 0`?

Comment: Use a variable that stores whether the previous number was odd or even. Then for every number, check whether or not it has the same evenness as the previous number. If you ever receive a number that does not have the same evenness as the previous number, set a Boolean variable that indicates that not all number were of the same evenness. After you process the `n`th input, you can determine just from those two Booleans the answer.

Comment: For n = 0 it should display an error message and i'm not sure how would I do it with an array , because the exercise says I cannot use arrays.

Comment: Why do you need an array? What would you store in it?

Comment: you should show what you've done so far so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the number `n` times whether if it's even or odd. Create two counters for even and odd and increment counters accordingly. In the end, return `-1` for even/odd, `0` for even and `1` for odd.

Note - In C, C++ the non-zero value is `true` while zero is taken as `false`.

```
int check(int n){
    int even=0, odd=0, num;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>num;
        if(num % 2 == 0)
            even++;
        else
            odd++;
        }

    if(even && odd){ 
        return -1;
    }else if(even){
        return 0;
    }else
        return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep two counters, one for the number of even numbers and one for the number of odd numbers.  For each number, you increment the appropriate counter.  Then after you've read all the numbers, you look at the counters.  If the even counter is 0 then return 1, if the odd counter is 0 then return 0, otherwise return -1.